# How to access constant values in an unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, unmanaged, dllexport

I have an unmanaged dll, inside which there is a constant value as the following:

`#define ProtocolVersion        1`

How can I access this value in C#?

p.s.: I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345034/getting-value-of-a-char-exported-by-unmanaged-dll-in-net) post but it didn't work.

Comment: That question doesn't deal with `#define` directives.  Does this answer your question? [Expose Unmanaged Code's Constant to Manage Dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381066/expose-unmanaged-codes-constant-to-manage-dll) or [Use C++ constants in C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3312335/150605)

Answer (score 1):

This is a preprocessor define and will not be compiled to the DLL. You can however create a C/C++ function returning this value and call it from C#. Something like:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetProtocolVersion()
{
    return ProtocolVersion;
}
```

and in C#:

```
[DllImport("MyDll")]
extern int GetProtocolVersion();
```